# Format Rules in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I'm setting up a spreadsheet which has a `date received` column and a `date acknowledged` column. I want the `date acknowledged` column to highlight red ten days after `date received` if the `date acknowledged` cell is blank, but once a date is entered in, it will returns to normal no color.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: What should trigger the conditional formatting - presumably M4 (acknowledged date) to be more than 10 days after L4? What if M4 is blank, does that get highlighted as well if today's date is > L4+10? You can do this in CF directly, no hidden columns required

Comment: hmmm not sure i know what you mean CF Directly?

Comment: I assume you are highlighting red by using conditional formatting (CF). I'm saying that you don't need a hidden column to do that, you can use a formula in conditional formatting

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your date received column is A and acknowledged is ColumnB, please select Column A and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
 =AND(ISBLANK(B1),TODAY()>A1+10,A1<>"")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, Fill, select red, OK, OK.